# Create referenced node on the fly in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities

I have a node called "house" which references another node called "room". When I create a house, i.e. go to node/add/house, there will be a block where I can choose all the rooms I've created. What I want instead is to create the room on the fly, right on that page, and then reference it automatically. So basically, next to where you can choose rooms, you must be able to click a button that says "create new" and then ajaxically it must then open a an area on the page where you can create room.

Does that make sense? Is there a way to do this? I have the entity reference part of things setup, but before I look into trying to figure out which hook to plug into, perhaps someone knows of an inherent way that already uses entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
>
> The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
> Existing entities can also be referenced.

Answer (score -1):

You could also look at
[Entity connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect)

> Entity Connect now expands both Entity reference and References (node_reference and user_reference) fields by adding "add new content" and "edit current content" buttons. It will work with all default widgets provided by Entity reference and References (node_reference and user_reference) .

or

[References dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog)

> This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog. This allows for a workflow where the user can create all the references to a node at the same time as she is creating it, a process which sometimes get's a bit backwards, when a user for instance needs to create all the facts for an article.